# Xunit test are not working getting internal server error when testing my api

Tags: c#, xunit

I am trying to test my api that I know works with xunit with the following code

```
  [Fact]
    public async Task TestCustomerStatusRebateCall()
    {
        var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>());
        var client = server.CreateClient();

        var response = await client.GetAsync("/Rebate/GetCustomerStatuses");

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
```

The error I am getting is the Assert.Equal failure expected Ok but got internal server error. I imagine its because it is not running but I can't run the test if the localhost is running

Comment: Can you debug the server to see why it's returning 500 Internal Server Error instead of 200 OK? There is nothing apparently wrong with the test, and your implementation of the server is not provided for answerers to assist you.

Comment: @AndrewH good call out I think because the server is just getting localhost and not localhost:44433

Comment: In that case, modify your test server and client to specify the correct port. Note that this test is an _integration test_, not a unit test. A unit test would make the assumption that the server connection exists (via mocking) and is either working or not working.